# Port not running but app wont stop running in browser - Windows - React - Node

Tags: node.js, npm, process, localhost, port

So when I go to localhost:3001 it shows project I worked on before. I restart my computer, its still there, kill all node/vscode processes in task manager, its still there. I tried the npx kill port 3001 - seems ok says "port killed" but, the app still there in localhost 3001. When I use netstat findstr 3001 shows nothing there. When I use CurrPort or cmd to check all ports listening - 3001 doesn't show up.

If I listen in port 3000, everything works normal, but when I npm start another app in React itll take me to port 3001 and it doesnt give any error. Except when it opens on Port 3001 it doesnt display the app I npm started in, it still shows that ghost app that I cant get out of port 3001.

In the network tab of the ghost app/port 3001 it shows port 3001 there. I cant post screenshots cus low reputation but idk if something with the initiators in network tab might give a hint to what the problem is.

I could always just set it so React uses 3002 onwards or just run one app at a time in port:3000 buts its bothering that this ghost app has taken over a port.

Hopefully its just something stupid Im overlooking, but if anybody ever had a similar experience let me know!

TL:DR my port 3001 is showing not running listening everywhere I check but everytime I go to it it shows this old project and if I try to run another app at the port terminal says its running, everything ok ,but it is still that old app still there

Comment: Please share your code so the community can try to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

So it seemed to be something with the browser not port, worked normal in another browser. So went into the inspector tools of the browser went in storage and deleted all cookies, cache, local&session storage and that fixed it. Also killing the service-worker.js process in the port worked for someone else who had the same problem from the project.